# What is the best way to find and print specific values by searching columns or locations in a certain order?

Tags: python, sql, if-statement, compare, comparison

Edited to add: Picture of desired output.

I am trying to do this in Python but I also have access to SQL. I've included a simple example picture but the dataframes I'm working with are 1000s of items long. Basically I need to find a way to search dataframe

1. based on the the values in dataframe
2. I need to find the Qty Needed of each Item Number from dataframe 2 in Dataframe 1 but I have to search in a specific order.

If the entire quantity is in FR then stop and print each Item Number, Bin Location, and WH Code. If the entire quantity is not in FR then look at PV next then LH until the full quantity is reached.

[image: dataframes]
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UB74z.jpg)

Comment: Which data frame of the two do you need to search and based on which value? Could you also add an example of what the output is supposed to look like?

Comment: I want data frame 2 to search data frame 1 based on Item Number. I want it to return only the total qty needed item numbers and print the item number each time and wh code and bin loc.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL:
You can run this query to get the results:

```
SELECT
    -- Select relevant columns
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        "Item Number"
        , "Qty Needed"
        , "FR Qty"
        , "PV Qty"
        , "LH Qty"
        , "WH Code"
        , "Bin Loc."
        , custom_order
        , (
            CASE
                WHEN row_val = "Qty Needed" THEN True
                ELSE False
                END
        ) AS selected
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            table1."Item Number"
            , table1."Qty Needed"
            , table1."FR Qty"
            , table1."PV Qty"
            , table1."LH Qty"
            , table2."WH Code"
            , table2."Bin Loc."
            -- Creating a custom order based on WH code
            , (
                CASE
                    WHEN table2."WH Code" == 'FR' THEN 1
                    WHEN table2."WH Code" == 'PV' THEN 2
                    WHEN table2."WH Code" == 'HR' THEN 3
                    ELSE 4
                END
            ) AS custom_order
            -- Will be used for matchin quantity available with quantity required
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY table1."Item Number" ORDER BY custom_order ASC) AS row_val
        FROM
            df2 AS table1
        LEFT JOIN
            df1 AS table2
        ON
            table1."Item Number" = table2."Item Number"

        ORDER BY
            table1."Item Number"
            , custom_order
    )
)
WHERE
    selected = True
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes a lot of sense. Is there a way to do it in Python? I thought it might be a nested for loop but I can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: Just a note, `WHERE SELECTED IS TRUE`, or just `WHERE SELECTED` would look _more ANSI SQL boolean_.

Comment: @Kate Welcome! I'll think of some way for doing it in python, but I think SQL would be more efficient